# Shows the live search result/s in the table using AJAX/Jquery in Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I would like to implement the live search through my table but I'm not using datatable in here. I copied the js that I've found in the internet and when I tried to search something, it doesnt return any result. Why? Can anyone help me?

**My view**

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('content')
<br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <h4>Live Search using Laravel</h4>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 pull-right" >

        <p class="pull-right">Click on the zip logo to download the file:<p>

            <a href="/live_search_laravel.zip" download="live-search(laravel).zip">
                <br><br>
                <img border="0" src="/images/ziplogo.png" class="pull-right" alt="AngularJS" width="50" height="42">

            </a>
        </div>



    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 pull-right">
        <input type="text" class = "form-control" id="search" placeholder="Live Search"></input>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">

            <div class="x_content">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Change File Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Original File Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                File Extension
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Category
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($data as $filename)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ $filename->rs_filename }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $filename->original_filename }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $filename->file_extension }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if($filename->category=="1")
                                {{ "Laravel" }}
                                @endif
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @stop
    @section('select2_js')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/live_search_laravel/select2.js"></script>

    @stop
```

**My JS**

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("th:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: did you check step by step in $("#search").on("keyup", function() { what valu you are getting?? like console.log(value);

Comment: Yes, its display the value that I input, I tried to console the $row.. There's some error, it said "Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined" at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous>,  at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (select2.js:7)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: try to do this $(this).css('background-color','red');then u can know what area it is belong...do u try console.log(index); ???what do u get??

Comment: As far as I understand my codes, it only search the first column. For example, the column I've is first_name, the search will only work on the first_name column and the rest can't be search..